# gSOAP instance of .NET service

Tags: wcf, gsoap

I have a linux c++ client (via gSOAP) to WCF c# server. The WCF c# service contains list of objects, on which some action is executed. Each time i call some function on service, the new object is created, action on that object is executed and that object lands into list in service. at the end i am calling another function on service, which loops over all objects in a list and executes another call on them. this works as intended on c#, with both client and service pure WCF.

it works different via gSOAP. each time i call a first function on service via gSOAP, that action is executed and list is updated. but it is each time new service. so basically i am dealing each time with new service. i do not wont serialize/deserialize object itself, to have it on inux side.

any ideas how to solve this?

on c# side i have something like (unnecessery details skipped)

```
    class Service : IService
    {
        List list = new List();
        void func1(int i)
        {
           Class1 c = new Class1(i);
           c.create();
           list.Add(c);
        }
        void func2()
        {
           foreach(Class1 c in list)
           {
               c.close();
           }
        }
    }
```

on gSOAP side i have something like

```
    Proxy service (endpoint);
    service.func1(1);
    service.func1(2);
    //...
    service.func2();
```

as i said problem is: when func2() is executed it operates on empty list, meaning gSOAP object of Proxy service does not contain c# object of service.

Help, help!

ps.
the solution is found: container made "static" does the trick.